# Modal not displaying in react-native?

Tags: view, modal-dialog, react-native, marker

Hey guys i am trying to show modal on click of map marker but i fail to see any modal on marker click can anybody help me out what is the issue. I am using Modal from https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox

Here is the code:

```
 import Modal from "react-native-modalbox";

export default class App {
openModal4(id) {
    this.refs.modal4.open();
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={style.mainContainer}>
            <MapView
                ref="map"
                showUserLocation={true}
                region={this.state.region}
                onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
                onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
                style={styles.map}
                rotateEnabled={false}
                showsCompass={false}
            >
                {this.state.markers.map(function(marker) {
                    return (
                        <MapView.Marker
                            coordinate={marker.latlng}
                            key={marker.id}
                            onPress={this.openModal4}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </MapView>
            <View
                style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    width: windowsWidth,
                    height: windowsHeight - 100,
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center"
                }}
            >
                <Image source={require("./assets/map-marker.png")} />
            </View>
            <Modal
                style={[styles.modal, styles.modal4]}
                position={"bottom"}
                ref={"modal4"}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show all code in file?

Comment: you can have a look now @stereodenis

Comment: what you use `extend React.Component` or `React.createClass`?

Comment: my answer is below

Answer (score 0):

You should make changes, to bind this in callbacks
read this article [Don't Use Bind When Passing Props](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/)

```
openModal4 = (id) => {
  this.refs.modal4.open();
}
```

Comment: i still can't see modal coming from bottom ?

Comment: could you call console.log(this.refs.modal4) in openModal4?

Comment: i can't see anything after console.log(this.refs.modal4)

Comment: try change to this
`<Modal style={[styles.modal, styles.modal4]} position={"bottom"} ref={(m) => this.modal4 = m}>`

and then call 
`openModal4 = (id) => {  this.modal4.open();}`

Answer (score 0):

Guys Binding was the issue which gets solved after using arrow function => 
here is the code

```
openModal4(id){
    this.refs.modal4.open();
  } 

{this.state.markers.map((marker) => {
            return(
              <MapView.Marker coordinate={marker.latlng} key={marker.id} onPress={this.openModal4} />
            );
          })}
```

And you need to bind the function in constructor as it consist of 'this'

```
this.openModal4 = this.openModal4.bind(this)
```

hope my struggle would help others